# Rattling noise in Bosch WFK2401UC Compact Washer on spin

Tags: washing-machine, washer, laundry

I have a compact Bosch stackable washer and dryer model #WFK2401UC. When it goes into the spin cycle, mainly when the revolutions are slower, it makes a rattling noise  like there is spare change rattling around in it.

I've had washers that get coins "stuck" in the washer drum fins  but I don't see how this is the case on this one. The fins seal pretty tight.

Some searches indicate that it's the bearings in the drum. I'm almost afraid to ask, What could the problem be?

Comment: Could be something simple as not bringing level, but usually when they spin up to speed.  Does drum feel like mounted well in machine or does it have a bit of give if moving it?

Comment: The washer does a great job washing clothes, high speed spin really drains them well too. Sooth operation overall, just noisy. Drum feels solid, and when rotated by hand turns smoothly and evenly.

Comment: Check if main bearing is failing by seeing if drum is sagging down.

Comment: There are a wide variety of on-line shops where you can get replacement parts for home appliances. I've found them to be mostly pretty reasonable, even when looking at parts for older washer/dryers. The biggest issue I had with replacing a belt/rollers/bearings on our dryer was making space to disassemble it in our cramped laundry room. Whether repair is "worth it" is totally on you, though, so I've removed that part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Indeed it was change in the washer. I removed the lower trim panel, drained the water out (there is a small hose with a cap), then removed the cover for the pump. Out fell a penny. That's right, a single penny made all that noise. The edges of the penny were silver from rolling around in the pump area. What uncovered this process for me was the manual detailing how to clean the pump:
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/19311/Bosch-Wfk-2401.html?page=19#manual
What a relief! Machine works great, no issues or noise now!

Answer (score 0):

Put head inside drum, rotate slowly. (The drum, not your head...) I once had to completely strip a machine, as a bra wire had escaped through a hole, and was catching outside the drum. Next port of call would be the pump itself, at the bottom of the machine. There could be something caught inside that, that is making the noise. Plenty of towels will soak up the inevitable water when you unscrew the bung.

Comment: I put my head in the drum and rotated it (the drum, not my head :) ), and didn't see anything obvious. Ran a partial load just now and waited for the spin cycle. When its on low speed spin, just before you hear the transmission kick in for higher speed, is when I hear the popcorn. Once the transmission kicks in, it is smooth sailing. The drum seems firm and tight, not sagging, doesn't move around much when I push it back and forth, up and down. The unit washes clothes really well (better than our Duet back at our last place), I just don't want it to stop suddenly and we're without a washer.

Comment: I have an update on this issue. I actually found myself in the laundry room at the exact moment the rattling started. The spin cycle had just started, but the drum was not turning at all. To be honest, it seemed like the rattling happened whenever the pump for draining the drum was going. It started low at the bottom of the machine, just a light rattling, but as more water poured into the drum for the rinse, and that water started to pump out, the rattling intensified. Eventually, the rattling stops as the spin continues, then as water accumulates, it starts rattling again.